# BASH exclude specific char from string

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I must implement one script, i should get list of virtual hosts apache:

```
apachectl -S | grep -i site | awk '{print $5}'
```

output:

```
Syntax OK
(/usr/local/apache2/conf/site.conf:1)
```

how can i receive this output? (without Syntax OK/()/:*):

```
/usr/local/apache2/conf/site.conf
```

Comment: Have you tried telling awk to output it?

Comment: Have you checked `tr`?

Comment: It's on stderr, redirect to dev/null `apachectl -S 2>/dev/null | yada yada`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` setting `(`, `)` and `:` as field separators, and getting the second field:

```
awk -F'[():]' '{print $2}'
```

**Example:**

```
% awk -F'[():]' '{print $2}' <<<'Syntax OK (/usr/local/apache2/conf/site.conf:1)'
/usr/local/apache2/conf/site.conf
```

Comment: Hi,ok but i have the :1 and Syntax line:

 apachectl -S | grep -i site | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}'
Syntax OK
/usr/local/apache2/conf/site.conf:1
/usr/local/apache2/conf/site.conf:18

Comment: @Luca No, you didn't run it correctly. Check again, you need include `:` as delimiter too. Do: `awk -F'[():]' '{print $2}'`

Comment: nope.. apachectl -S | grep -i site | awk -F'[():]' '{print $2}'
Syntax OK
/usr/local/apache2/conf/site.conf
/usr/local/apache2/conf/site.conf

Answer (score 1):

The Syntax OK text must be going to stderr, it's not going to stdout or it'd get filtered out by the grep/awk. Try this:

```
apachectl -S 2>&1 | awk '$5~/site/{gsub(/^\(|:[^:]+\)$/,"",$5); print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression to capture from the opening parenthesis to the ":"

```
apachectl -S 2>&1 | perl -ne '/\((.*site.*):/i && {print $1}'
```

Comment: nope apachectl -S | perl -ne '/\((.*site.*):/i && {print $1}'
Syntax OK